# How can I read from a Windows shared drive in a platform independent way using Java?

Tags: java, windows, jcifs

How can I read from a Windows shared drive using Java in such a way that the Java code which performs the reading could run equally correctly on any platform?

Comment: Isn't it "Windows share drive" and "platform independent" a contradiction?

Comment: @kgiannakakis: Only as much as "How can I ssh into a Solaris machine in a platform indepenent way?" is a contradiction. So no: it's perfectly possible to do that without restricting the set of machines the *client* runs on (at least without restricting it further than "anything that runs Java").

Comment: @kgiannakakis I've changed the wording.  Maybe it makes more sense to you now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) to access SMB/CIFS shares using pure Java code.

Answer (score 0):

[apache commons vfs](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) is always a good choice.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately the CIFS support doesn't seem to be officially released yet.